# Room flow not emitting on insert/update/upsert

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, android-room, kotlin-flow

I'm having issues where I have a flow of Room data that doesn't emit updates when changes are made to the underlying database table.

**API Service**

```kotlin
interface AtemsService {

    @GET("$PATH/data/_apps.json")
    suspend fun getPackageData(): Map<String, AtemsPackageInfo>
}
```

**Remote Impl**

```kotlin
class AtemsRemoteImpl @Inject constructor(private val atemsService: AtemsService) : AtemsRemote {

    override suspend fun getAtemsPackageData(): Map<String, AtemsPackageInfo> =
        atemsService.getPackageData()
}
```

**Local Dao**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface AtemsPackageDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<LocalAtemsPackage>

    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsertAll(localAtemsPackages: List<LocalAtemsPackage>)
}
```

**Repo Impl**

```kotlin
class AtemsPackageRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val atemsRemote: AtemsRemote,
    private val atemsPackageDao: AtemsPackageDao,
    private val atemsPackageMapper: AtemsPackageMapper,
) : AtemsPackageRepository {

    override fun observeAtemsPackages(): Flow<List<AtemsPackage>> {
        return flow {
            val localAtemsPackages = atemsPackageDao.getAll()
            emit(atemsPackageMapper.localToDomain(localAtemsPackages))
            if (localAtemsPackages.isEmpty()) {
                val fetchRemotePackages = atemsRemote.getAtemsPackageData()
                val convertToLocal = atemsPackageMapper.remoteToLocal(fetchRemotePackages)
                atemsPackageDao.upsertAll(convertToLocal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Use Case**

```kotlin
class AppsUseCaseImpl @Inject constructor(
    atemsPackageRepository: AtemsPackageRepository,
) : AppsUseCase {

    override val observeApps: Flow<List<AtemsPackage>> = atemsPackageRepository.observeAtemsPackages()
}
```

**View Model**

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class SidePanelAppListViewModel @Inject constructor(appsUseCase: AppsUseCase) : ViewModel() {

    val apps = appsUseCase.observeApps.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = WhileUiSubscribed,
        initialValue = emptyList()
    )
}
```

and finally;
**View**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SidePanelAppList(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: SidePanelAppListViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    val apps by viewModel.apps.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    SidePanelAppList(
        modifier = Modifier.then(modifier),
        apps = apps
    )
}
```

Everything is working as expected except when the method in the repo makes a network call to retrieve data, despite successfully saving the data to the Room database, my ui layer doesn't collect/display the updates unless the app is restarted. Any guidance would be immensely appreciated!

**Update**

Following the very helpful steer in the right direction by Tenfour04, I finished up with this (requirements changed slightly as I now update based on a value retrieved from the remote.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
override fun observeAtemsPackages(): Flow<List<AtemsPackage>> =
    atemsPackageDao.observeAll().transformLatest {
        val lastLocalUpdate = settingsDataStore.getAtemsRemoteLastUpdate.first()
        val lastRemoteUpdate = atemsRepoRemote.getAtemsLastUpdate().lastUpdated
        if (lastRemoteUpdate > lastLocalUpdate) {
            val fetchRemotePackages = atemsRepoRemote.getAtemsPackageData()
            val convertToLocal = atemsPackageMapper.remoteToLocal(fetchRemotePackages)
            atemsPackageDao.upsertAll(convertToLocal)
            settingsDataStore.setAtemsRemoteLastUpdate(lastRemoteUpdate)
        }
        emit(atemsPackageMapper.localToDomain(it))
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow you created in the observe method never emits anything after updating the database. I think it would be cleanest to have your DAO expose the list as a Flow, and use an `onEach` to trigger your fetch if needed.

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface AtemsPackageDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<LocalAtemsPackage>>

    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsertAll(localAtemsPackages: List<LocalAtemsPackage>)
}
```

In your repo implementation:

```
override fun observeAtemsPackages(): Flow<List<AtemsPackage>> 
    = atemsPackageDao.getAll()
        .onEach {
            if (it.isEmpty()) {
                val fetchRemotePackages = atemsRemote.getAtemsPackageData()
                val convertToLocal = atemsPackageMapper.remoteToLocal(fetchRemotePackages)
                atemsPackageDao.upsertAll(convertToLocal)
            }
        }
```

Now your flow is purely returning up-to-date database status. The `onEach` action is a side effect.

If it’s possible you can fetch an empty list, you probably need to do something so it only attempts the fetch once:

```
override fun observeAtemsPackages(): Flow<List<AtemsPackage>> 
    = flow {
        val source = atemsPackageDao.getAll()
        if (source.first().isEmpty()) {
            val fetchRemotePackages = atemsRemote.getAtemsPackageData()
            val convertToLocal = atemsPackageMapper.remoteToLocal(fetchRemotePackages)
            atemsPackageDao.upsertAll(convertToLocal)
        }
        emitAll(source)
    }
```